# Using an MySQL query stored in a db in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db of MySQL queries that I need to output in PHP. The queries include < and > in them and these are getting converted to html tags so the whole query is not outputting. How do I output it without the <> changing?

```
SELECT
  (CASE WHEN measure_start IS NULL AND fy_month = 1 AND fy_day = 1
    THEN YEAR(measure_date)
   WHEN measure_start IS NULL AND MONTH(measure_date) > fy_month
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(measure_date), '' - '', YEAR(measure_date) + 1)
   WHEN measure_start IS NULL AND MONTH(measure_date) > fy_month
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(measure_date) - 1, '' - '', YEAR(measure_date))
   WHEN measure_start IS NULL AND MONTH(measure_date) = fy_month AND DAY(measure_date) >= fy_day
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(measure_date), '' - '', YEAR(measure_date) + 1)
   WHEN measure_start IS NULL AND MONTH(measure_date) = fy_month AND DAY(measure_date) < fy_day
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(measure_date) - 1, '' - '', YEAR(measure_date))
   WHEN measure_date IS NULL AND fy_month = 1 AND fy_day = 1
     THEN YEAR(measure_start)
   WHEN measure_date IS NULL AND MONTH(measure_start) > fy_month
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(measure_start), '' - '', YEAR(measure_start) + 1)
   WHEN measure_date IS NULL AND MONTH(measure_start) < fy_month
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(measure_start) - 1, '' - '', YEAR(measure_start))
   WHEN measure_date IS NULL AND MONTH(measure_start) = fy_month AND DAY(measure_start)d>=fy_day
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(measure_start), '' - '', YEAR(measure_start) + 1)
   WHEN measure_date IS NULL AND MONTH(measure_start) = fy_month AND DAY(measure_start) < fy_day
     THEN CONCAT(YEAR(measure_start) - 1, '' - '', YEAR(measure_start)) END) AS ''Year '',
  amount                                                                     AS amount,
  cost                                                                       AS cost
FROM data_operations
  LEFT JOIN data_measure ON data_operations.measure = data_measure.id
  INNER JOIN profile_locationmeta ON data_operations.loc_id = profile_locationmeta.loc_id
WHERE data_operations.id IN (SELECT MAX(id)
                             FROM data_operations
                             GROUP BY parent_id)
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Do you want the query to be displayed inside a website (html)? If thats the case, you should have a look at the php-functions `htmlspecialchars` and/or `htmlentities`

Comment: I want to use the stored query to perform another query to generate a table. $chart_rows = $wpdb->get_results( "$query"); htmlspecialchars and htmlentities makes the query not work. $query is the one stored in the DB I'm having issues with

Comment: It's worth point out that storing queries in the database is usually a super bad idea as it makes it easier to compromise and inject arbitrary SQL code. For "canned queries" you may want to use stored procedures or views.

Comment: Thanks @tadman creating a view has solved my issue

Comment: It is strange why you'd want to store SQL statements as a String/Text. Why not store them as procedures?

Comment: can you change the way to store sql statements in the db ? I'm thinking maybe  ( serialize and unserialize  ) or ( base64_encode and base64_decode ) could help

Answer (score 1):

Use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to echo it on your website.
Assuming that your query is inside the $query variable, that's how you print it

`echo htmlspecialchars($query, ENT_QUOTES);`